# I want to call input() once and use it in multiple places

Tags: python

I want to put my code in exact one line, this is my code and it's working but I have no idea how can I use the input function in it :

```
input_string = str(input())
print(' '.join(sorted([input_string[i] if (ord(input_string[i]) - 97) % 2 == 0 else input_string[i].upper() for i in range(len(input_string))] , reverse=True)))
```

Comment: Do you have a shortage of lines or something?

Comment: Sounds more like a question for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have str(input()) there

Comment: I just want to embed the first line in the second one, but if I replace ```input_string``` with ```input()``` it has a different result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to save you having to include it in multiple places is to only use it once. The reason you're using it multiple times is because you're using the

```py
for i in range(len(string)):
    # use string[i]
```

pattern which is almost always the wrong thing to do. If you only need the characters you can use `for c in string:` and not bother with indices at all. Changing your code to use this approach you get

```py
input_string = str(input())
print(' '.join(sorted([c if (ord(c) - 97) % 2 == 0 else c.upper() for c in input_string] , reverse=True)))
```

From here you can see that you're only using the string once so you can replace it with the call to input directly. Worth noting as well that `input()` already returns a string so you don't need to call `str()`.

```py
print(' '.join(sorted([c if (ord(c) - 97) % 2 == 0 else c.upper() for c in input()] , reverse=True)))
```

This is a tangent but while we're changing things anyway: `(ord(c) - 97) % 2 == 0` is a bit redundant. In python [numbers can be used as booleans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth) with 0 being `False` and everything else being `True`. You are also subtracting a constant odd number before checking if it's even/odd so the result is always going to be the opposite of what it would otherwise be. This means the original condition is the same as `(ord(c) % 2) == 1` which is the same as `ord(c) % 2` leaving

```py
print(' '.join(sorted([c if ord(c) % 2 else c.upper() for c in input()] , reverse=True)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: the assignment expression is introduced for Python 3.8+.

You can use the [assignment expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/).
Since assignment expression cannot be used in a comprehension iterable expression, you can do a hack here:

```py
print((input_string := str(input())).removeprefix(input_string) + ' '.join(sorted([input_string[i] if (ord(input_string[i]) - 97) % 2 == 0 else input_string[i].upper() for i in range(len(input_string))] , reverse=True)))
```

Comment: do you have any idea to do the same thing for older versions?

Comment: @mohammad Well, after some thinking I come up with another one-liner without using the assignment expression: `globals().__setitem__("input_string", input()) or print(' '.join(sorted([input_string[i] if (ord(input_string[i]) - 97) % 2 == 0 else input_string[i].upper() for i in range(len(input_string))] , reverse=True)))`. This should work for lower versions of Python. However this is another hack which I recommend not to use in real code.